# Python: add new functions to the list structure, under a different name

Tags: python, list, class

This is a slightly unique request. I am looking to see if it is possible add additional functions to the **list()** data structured, like 'append' I would like to add coordinate rotation under a new class name that inherits the properties of **list**:

```
class __VecRot(list):

    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = coords
        print coords        

    def double(self):
        self.coords = [i*2 for i in self.coords]

a = __VecRot([1,0,0])
```

That line of code initializes the coordinates, but it doesn't define 'a' as a list with values in of [1,0,0]. Such that when this code is executed.

Currently

```
print a

>>> a
[]
```

I am looking for

```
print a

>>> a
[1,0,0]
```

and additional functions such that the following is true:

```
a.double()
print a
>>> a
[2,0,0]
```

Is it possible to define a class a value? such that it can carry the existing data structure?

Comment: Consider subclassing `UserList` instead of `list` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're duplicating the actual container. If you derive from `list` you already have a storage. Consider this:

```
 class __VecRot(list):

     def __init__(self, coords):
         list.__init__(self, coords)

     def double(self):
         for i in range(len(self)):
             self[i] = self[i] * 2

 a = __VecRot([1,0,0])

 a.double()

 print a
```

Or if you have the `coords` field anyway, you don't need to derive from `list`:

```
 class __VecRot:

     def __init__(self, coords):
         self.coords = coords

     def double(self):
         self.coords = [i*2 for i in self.coords]

     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.coords)

     def __str__(self):
         return "__VecRot["+str(self.coords)+"]"

     def __repr__(self):
         return "__VecRot("+repr(self.coords)+")"

 a = __VecRot([1,0,0])

 a.double()

 print a
```

Which seems a better practice. You should also overload other list-interface methods (like `__getitem__`). Because of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in Python it doesn't really matter if your class derives from `list`, as long as it contains all the necessary methods.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it. I have now to figure out why it works with a simple function but not with a large function including operations from Numpy.

Comment: Ahh... great now I understand what you mean by duplicating the container. By using `self = blah blah` i redefine `self`, thus it is ignored in the call. When I save to `self[:] = blah blah` I see it keeps the same container. Thanks

Comment: @CromeX Yes, exactly. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to inherit from the `list` class to make your own custom functions within the `list` scope. You are doing it wrong.

It is much simpler than you think:

```
class __VecRot(list):

    def double(self):
        self[:] = [i*2 for i in self[:]]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> a = __VecRot([1,0,0])
>>> a
[1, 0, 0]
>>> a.double()
>>> a
[2, 0, 0]
>>> a.double()
>>> a
[4, 0, 0]
```